# Scala filter a sequence to map with elements that respect and not respect filter condition

Tags: scala, filter

I have a Sequence of Strings:

```
val results = Seq("", "one", "two", "three")
```

With two filter I get:

```
val emptyStrings: Seq[String] = results.filter( s => s.isEmpty )
val notEmptyStrings: Seq[String] = results.filterNot( s => s.isEmpty )
```

Is it possible to get with one filter a `Map[Boolean, Seq[String]]` with:

- key = isEmpty true/false
- values = empty or not empty strings

Answer (score 5):

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.13.0 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_262).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> val results = Seq("", "one", "two", "three")
results: Seq[String] = List("", one, two, three)

scala> results.groupBy(_.isEmpty)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Boolean,Seq[String]] = HashMap(false -> List(one, two, three), true -> List(""))
```

A better option would be usage of `partition` due it returns a tuple with 2 values instead of a map:

```
scala> results.partition(_.isEmpty)
res1: (Seq[String], Seq[String]) = (List(""),List(one, two, three))
```

or even better to pattern match the result to named values:

```
scala> val (emptyStrings, nonEmptyStrings) = results.partition(_.isEmpty)
emptyStrings: Seq[String] = List("")
nonEmptyStrings: Seq[String] = List(one, two, three)
```